# Disable registration on certain condition

Tags: login, user-registration

I have a certain condition in my code (if the user is visiting the page from a network range) and I can ask for this condition easily, let's say:

```
if ( $user_in_allowed_range)
```

What I want is to offer the registration button only to users who fulfill this condition, and other users should still be able to login.

Is there any way to do this in WordPress without hacking the core? An additional custom login form is not a solution as the original one is still available.

I found some hooks (`login_form`, `login_head`, `user_register` …) and the theme function `wp_login_form()` but they do not offer my needed feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `get_option('users_can_register')` will return the setting value for the "Anyone can register" setting used for displaying the registration link, you could probably add a `get_option` filter overriding the value for the `users_can_register` key. In this case i even think the [`pre_option_%s`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/option.php#L40) filter is your best bet, since the actual value of the settings is irrelevant. Something like this might work:

```
add_filter('pre_option_users_can_register', 'wpse_87341_users_can_register');

function wpse_87341_users_can_register() {
    // Obviously here you'd populate $user_in_allowed_range
    // ...

    return intval($user_in_allowed_range); // We need to return an int since get_option does not like false return values
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it and come back with the result. :)

Comment: Okay, it does not work yet. The function returns false, but I can still access /wp-login.php?action=register.

Comment: btw.: I have added the code in my functions.php

Comment: Whoops, turns out `get_option` validates the return value of `pre_option_%s` filters to make sure it is not explicitly `false` (i.e. checking `!==`), since this can also mean the value is inexistent. Returning either `0` or `1` instead appears to be working fine. I've updated my example to reflect this fact.